# вложенные категории django+jquaery

Tags: jquery, django

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать подобную структуру на django+jquery?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

class Subcategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Подкатегория')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', verbose_name='Категория', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cates')

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='products', verbose_name='Категория', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('Subcategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Подкатегория', blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name='Название')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
```

Comment: Подход неверный. Убирайте подкатегории. И применяйте деревья (например, treebeard или mptt)

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 Понял. Буду менять. Но как результат вывести в jquery?

Comment: Если у вас категорий меньше тысячи, то просто выводите шаблонизатором обычную html-разметку.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как осуществить вывод соответствующих подкатегорий. Каким образом системе дать понять, что при mouseenter - "Игрушки" должен выпасть список с "Машинки, Куклы, Развивающие" к примеру.

Comment: @Ivan https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#template